# RecyclerView Edittext Position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I am searching for an item inside the recycle view but what's happening is when I enter one item quantity as shown in the first image and when I search another item that quantity sticks to another edit text as shown in image two.

I don't know how to manage the edit text position I have tried to get Item View Type and get Item Id as well but no fruitful result.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're checking for the quantity value before setting it inside the EditText you should clear the value in your else statement like below:

```
  if (quantatiy != null){
      quantatiyEditTxt.setText(quantatiy);
   }else{
      quantatiyEditTxt.setText("");
   }
```

This bug is very common when you forgot to handle your else statement inside the `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Thank you so much that's what i was looking for you saved my day.

Comment: You're welcome :). It would be better If you posted your code within the question next time to add more clarity to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:left` or `android:right` attributes to anchor items, you can use also `android:toEndOf` or `android:toStartOf` for other issues.

Comment: That's not the problem,its the problem for searching an item. its showing the edit text value of first edit text into the one i searched